# IOError: request data read error

Tags: django, mod-wsgi, wsgi, ioerror, django-wsgi

I'm getting an IO request data read error when trying to loading data as Excel in response.

```
def convert_to_excel(request):
    field = forms.CharField()
    try: data = field.clean(request.POST.get('exceldata', ''))
    except: data = u''
    response = render_to_response("spreadsheet.html", request= request, dictionary = locals())
    filename = "%s%s.xls" % ("report_excel", datetime.datetime.today().strftime('%Y%m%d%H%M%S'))
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename='+filename
    response['Content-Type'] = 'application/vnd.ms-excel; charset=utf-8'
    return response
```

It works fine when the data is under 150k, but the bigger file fails at around 200k. I'm running django 1.4 Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu) mod_wsgi/3.3 with daemon mode and Python/2.7.3.

This works fine in localhost. I guess this might be an issue or bad configuration of wsgi with daemon mode. Does anyone know about this?

The exception I am getting is below.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 89, in get_response
   response = middleware_method(request)

 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/newrelic-1.2.1.265-py2.7.egg/newrelic/hooks/framework_django.py", line 191, in __call__
   result = self.__wrapped(*args, **kwargs)

 File "/home/core/mysite/src/task/tools/libs/pagination/middleware.py", line 8, in process_request
   request.page = int(request.REQUEST.get('page', 1) )

 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 166, in _get_request
   self._request = datastructures.MergeDict(self.POST, self.GET)

 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 180, in _get_post
   self._load_post_and_files()

 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/http/__init__.py", line 360, in _load_post_and_files
   self._post, self._files = self.parse_file_upload(self.META, data)

 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/http/__init__.py", line 320, in parse_file_upload
   return parser.parse()

 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/newrelic-1.2.1.265-py2.7.egg/newrelic/api/function_trace.py", line 82, in __call__
   return self._nr_next_object(*args, **kwargs)

 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/http/multipartparser.py", line 161, in parse
   data = field_stream.read()

 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/http/multipartparser.py", line 301, in read
   out = ''.join(parts())

 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/http/multipartparser.py", line 285, in parts
   yield ''.join(self)

 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/http/multipartparser.py", line 316, in next
   output = self._producer.next()

 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/http/multipartparser.py", line 449, in next
   for bytes in stream:

 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/http/multipartparser.py", line 316, in next
   output = self._producer.next()

 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/http/multipartparser.py", line 377, in next
   data = self.flo.read(self.chunk_size)

 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/http/__init__.py", line 384, in read
   return self._stream.read(*args, **kwargs)

 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 104, in read
   result = self.buffer + self._read_limited(size - len(self.buffer))

 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 92, in _read_limited
   result = self.stream.read(size)

 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/newrelic-1.2.1.265-py2.7.egg/newrelic/api/web_transaction.py", line 349, in read
   data = self.__input.read(*args, **kwargs)

IOError: request data read error
```

Comment: Were you able to resolve this?

Answer (score 3):

check your apache config, and see whether you could find `LimitRequestBody`

if so, change it to a bigger number, if not find, under your site config, add following piece

```
LimitRequestBody 1024000000
```

also, check your uwsgi's file limit option, start your uwsgi with following option:

```
uwsgi --limit-post 1024000000
```

this kind of error is your upload exceeds your apache/nginx/uwsgi max upload setting. also I notice you may not using uwsgi, [limit request body](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4467443/limitrequestbody-doesnt-respond-with-413-for-large-file25mb) and [set LimitRequestBody to be a low value by default](http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/issues/detail?id=207)  might help.

Comment: LimitRequestBody is 104857600. 
Changed to 1024000000 as you recommended, but still the same

Comment: @zomboid  uwsgi has some file limit, say "--limit-post 65536" if you start uwsgi with this option, and check to see whether it solves your problem